# Is it possible, to calculate the number of matches in mysql like structure?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets assume i have a query like the following

```
$query_search = "SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$word%' OR `content` LIKE '%$word%'";
```

i need to order rows by count of matches?

is it possible in such structure of database, or i need to redesign it?

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax may be a bit off but would something like the following work?

```
ORDER BY 
 COALESCE(LENGTH(`title`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`title`,'$word','')),0)+
      COALESCE(LENGTH(`content`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`content`,'$word','')),0) 
DESC
```

The number of matches in the string can be determined by `(LEN(string)-Len(ReplacedString))/Len(Word)`

As `Len(Word)` is a constant and won't affect the relative ordering I have left it out in the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ORDER BY  (CASE WHEN title REGEXP $word then 1 else 0 end +
              CASE WHEN content REGEXP $word then 1 else 0 end) DESC
```